# Discord.py text writing and reading text file

Tags: python, discord, text-files, discord.py

I wanted to make command for my bot, to switch automod (The `on_message` event will be reading file and if it's true before moderating), but bot doesn't launch. Please help:

Command:

```
@bot.command()
async def automod(ctx, status):
    if status='enable':
        with open('automod.txt', 'w') as wf:
            wf.write("true")
    if status='disable':
        with  open('automod.txt', 'w') as wf:
            wf.write("false")
```

`on_message` event (How can i make reading file btw):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            botmsg1 = await message.channel.send(f'Deleted {message.author.mention} for using bad words.')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await botmsg1.delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
if status='enable'
```

First of all, comparison uses **two** `=` operators, so these two should be

```py
if status == "enable"
..
if status == "disable"
```

This will most likely make compilation fail, so it won't start. You should've gotten an error from that though. If that's not the issue, then you need to post more of your code.

As for your second question (`how to read a file in python`), you can easily find this by googling "python read file". Try doing minimal effort into looking something up before asking a question.

Comment: Ok, but it don't writes in the file.

Comment: Are you calling the command properly? Try printing something in that `if` to see if your code even gets there. Also, does the file exist? Is the path correct? Does your script have permissions to read/write in that directory? Are you getting any errors?